# Clear html input type="number" onFocus without warning or start without a value React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I wan't to either clear an html input of a previous set number `onFocus` or start with an empty field.

`salary: null` in constructor warning on page load:

> Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an
>   empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled
>   components.

`salary: undefined` in constructor and then start typing in input field:

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type number
>   to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled
>   to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More
>   info: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

`salary: 0` in constructor, `onFocus={() => this.setState({salary: null})}` in input field and when I click the field I get both errors above and the 0 is still present in the input field.

The only way I got it working was by setting `salary: any` in `IState` and then set `salary: ''` in constructor. I can't set `salary: number | string` because then functions like `Math.round` will give me a TypeScript error. Is there any other way to solve this?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { FormControl } from "react-bootstrap"

interface IProps {    
}

interface IState {
    salary: number
}

export class Taxes extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            salary: 0,
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event: any) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render() {
         return (
            <div>
                <FormControl
                    name="salary"
                    type="number"
                    value={this.state.salary}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    //onFocus={() => this.setState({salary: 0})}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: How about doing something like `Math.round(parseInt(salary))`?

Comment: @bennygenel I would need to do `parseInt` everywhere I use `salary` then. I went with `any` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `value={this.state.salary ? this.state.salary : "0"}` for the value prop for `FormControl`. This would remove the warning for the input being null and you can still use it as a number in other functions like `Math.round()`